# Insert a date in a cell in sc

Tags: spreadsheet, sc-spreadsheet

In sc (spreadsheet calculator), I formatted a column with `<f 12 0 3>` but was unable to insert a valid date in its cells. If I digit `<\^D15/12/31>` (or other similar notations, with or without the initial `^D`, I only get a string with no possibility to calculate date-differences.
Could somebody give me any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a date using the `@dts` function, eg `=@dts(15,12,31)`. When needed it is converted to a number of seconds since the epoch so you can calculate a difference. Eg if cell `A1` has this value, and cell `A2` has a day earlier `=@dts(15,12,30)`, then you can set `B1` to `=A1-A2` and it will show `86400.00`, i.e. the difference in seconds.

I don't think you can do anything else with this time difference except the usual arithmetic. You can use `^D` (control-D) to change the display format. For example, type `F^D%T` whilst over the `B1` cell and it will now show as *hours:mins:secs* `01:00:00` (see man strftime for `%T`), but it is still "seconds from epoch", so you cannot for example convert it into a number of weeks except by dividing by the appropriate number of seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Meuh: you saved me a lot of time! That indication in 'man sc' about the CTRL+D at the beginning of the string to make the string identified as a date was really deceiving me. Do you have any further reading to suggest about this lovely 'vintage' spreadsheet calculator?

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the answer, it is possible to enter both date and time, then format the entry to expectations.

Cell info, (format codes) [two formulas]:

```
B18 (^D%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S) [@dts(2022,5,4)+@tts(8,30,45)]
```

The method:

- Select a cell for date-time entry
- Press <kbd>e</kbd>
- `@dts(2022,5,4)+@tts(8,30,45)` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>F</kbd>
- `"^D%m/%d/%y&nbsp;&nbsp;%H:%M:%S"` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>f</kbd>, then press <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase L) repeatedly til good width, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Essential for the format string is to actually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then enter codes. See "man date" for possible codes. Formulas begin with `@`, where `@dts(y,m,d)` converts a date, and `@tts(H,M,S)` converts a time; both convert to seconds from epoch and can be added for a true date and time.

Also useful is `man sc`, and in `sc` press <kbd>?</kbd> to see a help menu, use keys <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>p</kbd> anywhere in that menu or sub-menus, or <kbd>q</kbd> to quit back to spreadsheet.

This is a nice shell spreadsheet utility; many built-in formulas including amortizing loan and others.